# How do I convert a string to a location and vice versa?

Tags: rascal

I would like to take a path to a method, like "p2-SnakesAndLadders/snakes/DieTest/reached", and convert it into a location by prepending "|java+method://" and using that string as a location. Conversely I would like to get the string value of a location.
Nothing in the documentation of Location or String seems to give a hint.

Answer (score 2):

The first you can do by adding the string to the end of the location, like so (I think you need three forward slashes, at least in my case I get a malformed URI exception if I only use two):

```
rascal>l = |java+method:///| + "p2-SnakesAndLadders/snakes/DieTest/reached";
loc: |java+method:///p2-SnakesAndLadders/snakes/DieTest/reached|
```

The second you can do using the path field

```
rascal>l.path;
str: "/p2-SnakesAndLadders/snakes/DieTest/reached"
```

If you want to get rid of the first slash, you can just do this instead

```
rascal>l.path[1..];
str: "p2-SnakesAndLadders/snakes/DieTest/reached"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. I also discovered that interpolation works nicely, so if I have a uri, then

```
uri == |<uri.scheme>://<uri.authority><uri.path>|
```